# How to assign JS array value to each div in javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload =init;

    function init(){

        $rlt = [1, 0, 0];

        //How to assign value of $rlt to each div
    }

</script>

        <div id="block1"></div>
        <div id="block5"></div>
        <div id="block7"></div>
```

How to assign value of $rlt to each div in javascript or Jquery?

**Final result should be:**

```
        <div id="block1">1</div>
        <div id="block5">0</div>
        <div id="block7">0</div>
```

Comment: Consider a class name to group the DIV's together... (or put them in a common container)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$( 'div' ).each( function ( i ) {
    $( this ).text( $rlt[i] );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pDwps/1/

or with regular JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ), function ( div, i ) {
    div.textContent = $rlt[i];
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pDwps/

Comment: Where did you get jQuery from?

Comment: @Neal From the question's tags?

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like:

```
var rlt = [1, 0, 0];

// Only if ID starts with block
$( "[id^=block]" ).each(function( index ){
    if( !rtl[index] ) return false; // Stop when out of index.
    $( this ).html( rlt[index] );
});
```

Comment: hehe where did the jQuery come from?

Comment: Did not really exist in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $rlt = [1, 0, 0];
    $("div[id^=block]").each(function(i) {
        $(this).html($rlt[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add the array values sequentially to each of the divs you can try this provided you include jQuery library into your page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $rlt = [1, 0, 0];
    $("div[id^=block]").each(function(i) {
        $(this).html($rlt[i].toString());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it just using javascript. jQuery is not required for this small code. you can avoid need of jquery plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;
function init(){
var $rlt = [1, 0, 0];
document.getElementById("block1").innerHTML  = $rlt[0];
document.getElementById("block5").innerHTML  = $rlt[1];
document.getElementById("block7").innerHTML  = $rlt[2];
}
</script>
```

check the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Wk6m8/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
var divs = getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0; i < $rlt.length && i < divs.length; i++) {
     divs[i].innerHTML = $rlt[i];
}
```

Or for a `jQuery` alternative:

```
var divs = $('div');

divs.each(function(i, div){
     div.innerHTML = $rlt[i];
});
```